# I just managed to SSH in to my reseller account without having to put in a password

Tags: unix, password-protection, shared-hosting

I followed their docs and wrote the following in terminal to ssh in

```
ssh -p 7822 userid@servernameexample.com
```

and got into the server, didn't get asked for a password - what could this mean?

If I try to ssh into any of the other accounts under the reseller account then I am asked for a password.

Answer (score 0):

passwordless SSH.Either your userid is whitelisted , or whole domain is whitelisted or may be you're internally accessing